# How do I replace these static JFrame variables?

Tags: java, swing, static, static-variables

I'm a freshman with all the GUI stuff and I want to know why do I have to declare all the JFrames with "static" in my code(otherwise it wont compile) and how can I modify my code to compile without declaring them "static"?

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame {
    private static JFrame frameInicio = new JFrame("Ingresar Datos");
    private static JFrame frameCrearUsuario = new JFrame("Crear Usuario");
    private static JFrame frameMenu = new JFrame("Menu Del Juego");
    private static JFrame frameJuego = new JFrame("El Ahorcado");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Inicio();
    }
    public static  void Inicio(){
        frameCrearUsuario.dispose();
        frameMenu.dispose();
        frameInicio.setSize(450,200);
        frameInicio.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameInicio.add(new FrameInicio());
        frameInicio.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        frameInicio.setVisible(true);       
    }

    public void CrearUsuario(){
        frameInicio.dispose();
        frameCrearUsuario.setSize(450,300);
        frameCrearUsuario.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameCrearUsuario.add(new FrameCrearUsuario());
        frameCrearUsuario.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        frameCrearUsuario.setVisible(true);     
    }

    public void Menu(){
        frameInicio.dispose();
        frameJuego.dispose();
        frameMenu.setSize(660,290);
        frameMenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameMenu.add(new FrameMenu());
        frameMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
        frameMenu.setVisible(true);     
    }
    public void Juego(){
        frameMenu.dispose();
        frameJuego.setSize(1100,800);
        frameJuego.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameJuego.add(new FrameJuego());
        frameJuego.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frameJuego.validate();
        frameJuego.setVisible(true);            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's becuase your `public static  void Inicio()` is static.  You can't call a non static property from a `static` method

Here's a common way to use a `JFrame`.  Create a constructor for the JFrame and add all the components inside of it.  Then just Create the JFrame object in the `main` method

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("button");
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();

    public Vantan(){
        add(panel);
        add(button);
        add(jta);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new Ventana();
        frame.setTitle("Frame);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaulCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This way you don't need the static properties as in your case.